# Не переведено сообщение при попытке отписаться от всех меток в настройках профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, профиль-участника

Не переведено сообщение при попытке [отписаться от всех меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/current).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В трансе строка [ce6764bdb669c8d50138176b44adc23e](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/139847582?q=key%3Ace6764bdb669c8d50138176b44adc23e).

Предложенный перевод:

> Вы больше не будете получать уведомления по меткам на Stack Overflow
>   на русском.

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить слово «сайт» и взять имя сайта в кавычки. Так как для сайта «Русский язык» (ибо общая база переводов) предложенный вариант будет выглядеть несколько странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подправил ваш вариант с учётом комментария про кавычки и "сайт".

Будет на сайте после череды обновлений.